# Story about diversifying your child's "life" portfolio

Tags: story-identification

I read the first couple of pages of a short scifi story book the other day, and became interested, but didn't think to get the name of the book.

Because I only read the first couple of pages, I don't have a lot of details, but I'll try to give as many as I can.

- The book I saw it in seemed like some sort of anthology, I remember perhaps a warm colored front (red/orange, but it looks like many of them fit this description) However, I don't believe that it was like Rich Horton's *The Year's Best Science Fiction & Fantasy* covers where it's mostly text with a small picture in the corner; the front cover was more of a scene, with smaller text.
- It starts from the narrator's perspective giving information on the state of the world, babies can be grown (maybe in artificial wombs).
- The narrator talks about how his older brother hadn't been born yet because his parent's couldn't afford it.
- He did have a younger sister, but can't remember if she had been born yet. I think he mentioned that her portfolio was in a better shape than his was.
- I think he indicated that he was "young" at ~80 years old.
- He felt disdain (maybe) about how his parents didn't properly diversify his genetic? portfolio, and so wasn't good at much
- I read it in a book that was a collection of short sci-fi stories, published recently (don't remember the date exactly, but April 2016 seems familiar, could have been on the other side of 2017/2018 though)
- I think the title of the book was something like *How much would you pay for your child's future?* or something to that effect.
- Because I don't remember the year exactly, it makes me think that it wasn't very prominent on the cover.

When I tried to search for this though, the only thing I could find were ads trying to sell me early college savings plans.

Comment: Sorry, his older brother hadn’t been born yet? Am I reading that right?

Comment: @Broklynite Yes, I believe so.

Comment: I am chronologically confused.

Comment: @Broklynite - Could be older in terms of conception, and with artificial wombs they could either "pause" the process, or leave the "kid" in the womb past the date when they *could* be born. Of course, we'd have to see the story to know for sure.